# Lambda Function Calculate Using BYROW

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

| NAME | SURNAME | DAY1 | DAY2 | DAY3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN | WILSON | X |  |  |
| JACK | HARRY | X | X | x |

I have a table as above AND I have the formula as follows

`=SORT(FILTER(A2:B,BYROW(C3:E,LAMBDA(ROW, COUNTA(ROW)<3)));1;1)`

this formula brings only the name and surname of people who work less than 3 days

what I want is to display both name, surname and working day using COUNTA.

because I don't want it to count empty cells

how can i do that?

Conclusion

| NAME | SURNAME | WORKDAY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOHN | WILSON | 1 |

1 person working less than 3 days

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ;byrow(C2:E;lambda(x;counta(x)));
     filter({A2:B\Σ}; isbetween(Σ;0;3;0;0)))
```

- *`John Doe` has **0 working days** in the test data & is skipped; let us know if 0 days needs to be tracked as well*

[image]